# Try to echo data from database with PDO but it's just blank

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

here is my code

categories_view.php

```html
<table width="100%" align="center" border=0 bordercolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr><td colspan=2 align="center" bgcolor="#0000CC"><?php header_web();?></td></tr>
<tr>
 <td width="200px" valign="top" bgcolor="white"><?php menu();?></td>
 <td valign="top"><p class="judul">CATEGORIES</p>
    <?php
 try {
   $link=connection();
   $sql="select * from category order by name"; 
   $result=$link->query($sql); 
   $record=$result->fetchColumn(); 
   if($record>0){ 
 ?> 
  <div align="center" class="info">Categories found : <b><?php echo $record;?></b> Record</div>
  <table border=0 align="center">
    <tr class="jtable"><td colspan=4>LIST OF CATEGORIES</td></tr>
    <tr class="jtable"><td>ID</td><td>NAME</td><td>DESCRIPTION</td><td>EDIT/DELETE</td></tr>
    <?php
     $i=0;
     while($data=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      $i++; 
    ?> 
     <tr class="<?php if($i%2==1) echo "oddtable"; else echo "eventable";?>">
        <td align="center"><?php echo $data['id_category'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data['name'];?></td> 
                           <td align="center"><?php echo $data['desc'];?></td>
                           <td align="center"><a href="category_edit.php?id_category=<?php echo $data['id_category'];?>"><img src="edit.png"></a> 
               <a href="category_del.php?id_category=<?php echo $data['id_category'];?>"><img src="delete.png"></a></td>
      </tr>
    <?php
     } 
    ?> 
  </table>
 <?php
 }
 else {
  echo "No data is found ";
 }
 }catch(PDOException $e){
   echo $e->getMessage();
  }
 ?>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan=2  bgcolor="#FFCC00"><?php footer_web();?></td></tr>
</table>
```

and here's the connection function in con.php

```
function connection(){
    try{
        $link= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbeorder","root","");
        $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
        echo "Error : ".$e->getMessage();
    }
    return $link;
}
```

it does return the value of $record=$result->fetchColumn() correctly.
but the table list of categories doesn't show anything, just blank. am i doing it wrong?

Comment: is the code entering the  `if($record>0){ ` statement? Try putting an echo after the if

Comment: i've tried it, to test the code. but nothing changed, just blank :(

Comment: so, it's not entering the if statement.What is the result of `var_dump($record)`? Put it just after  `$record=$result->fetchColumn();`

Comment: it's "string '1' (length=1)".

Comment: or is it something wrong with the code inside "while($data=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))" because i tried to echo the $data values ?

Comment: if you have put ah `echo` just after the `if($record>0){` and it doesn't echo anything, the problem is before...try to replace the `if($record>0){` with `if ( $record )`

Comment: still blank :( you're right, the problem is in "if($record>0)" statement, i tried to put :
$data=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $data['name']; after $res=$link->query($sql);
it does return the right value.
but i need to put it on the table

Comment: try removing the if and check if it works :)

Comment: still blaaannnkkk... i don't get it :(
but how can i make an echo where "No data is found" if i removing the if statement?

Comment: just trying to undnerstand where the problem is...so the code stops just after '$record=$result->fetchColumn();'.Try removing one by one the line following it ( or remove all the lines and write a test line with some custom text) to see if it's printed

Comment: i would do this way to understand where the problem is: remove all the PHP code following $record=$result->fetchColumn(); (also the footer call ), than assure than the code goes after that line, writing in the document a simple test string. Once you've checked that, add one block of code at a time, to see what is causing the problem

Comment: i removed all
the PHP code following $record=
$result->fetchColumn(); 
then echoing the data. it does return values, but only 1 row.
i need all of it. so i put the while statement.
then it's blank again when i put "while($data..." before echo anything.
(i tried it without put the if statement of course)

Comment: Try to remove the statement $record=$result->fetchColumn() and the if, to see it it works. Or try to use $records = $result->fetchAll(), in place of the while loop, to fetch all the results in $records, then iterate the results with a foreach, printing the rows

Answer (score 0):

You don't require `fetchColumn()` `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` returns an array where you can use `count()`

```
......
$data=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  if(count($data)>0){ 
      ...
      foreach ($data as $data){ 
              .............. 
              <td align="center"><?php echo $data['id_category'];?></td>
              ..............
```